# Starbattle - Whats the point of the quantum reactor for the Colossus. When is the best time to get it?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm a passionate Starbattle player and was wondering how I would go about finding out when the best time was to get quantum reactor which gives 25% shield recharge during sustained fire vs 0% under sustained fire. It costs 150 minerals.

My view would be to get it from the get go since it its a passive ability.

Starbattle is a game that can be played in the arcade of Starcraft II.

Answer (score 1):

As always with questions like these, this depends. The most straightforward answer would be once that 25% grants you more benefit then investing 150 minerals for another colossus. So that takes into account how much of other resources you need and how hard they are to obtain and the firepower of another colossus.

Obviously if get this on the get go your first colossi are tougher and there is less chance of them getting killed. But if you micromanage well and repair this would be neglect able.